How do I add the original commit hash to the commit message when using the NPM package gh-pages?
I have a Svelte/TS project with an NPM script called "deploy" that uses gh-pages to commit the contents of my build/dist folder to a branch called gh-pages for automatic deploy on Github Pages.
This package uses the commit message "Updates" by default, and I want to change it to contain the hash of the commit I'm in when I fire the script. If possible I don't want to install anything else or write more than a inline NPM script.
I'm running these scripts from VS Code on Windows 10 (I'm not sure if this is relevant), but the solution should work on Linux too.
I tried these commands, after the first failure I tried asking ChatGPT for help, also with no success:
Script: "deploy": "gh-pages --dist build --dotfiles --message \"$(git rev-parse HEAD)\""
Result: Commit message = $(git rev-parse HEAD) (literally)
Script: "deploy": "gh-pages --dist build --dotfiles --message $(git rev-parse HEAD)"
Result: Commit message = $(git (also literally)
Script: "deploy": "git_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD) && gh-pages --dist build --dotfiles --message \"Deploying commit $git_commit\""
Result: Error = 'git_commit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In the end I wrote a js script in another file.
const ghpages = require('gh-pages');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

try {
    const commitHash = execSync('git rev-parse HEAD').toString().trim();
    ghpages.publish('build', {
        dotfiles: true,
        message: `Deploying commit ${commitHash}`
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) console.error('Deployment error:', err);
        else console.log('Deployed successfully');
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching commit hash:', error);
}

Called from package.json with:
"deploy": "node scripts/deploy.cjs"

